# Passing pointer to function creating (randomly sized) array filled with random integers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

## Problem:

I'm rather sure my issue here is a typical misunderstanding of what's happening with pointers. I'll post what's happening in memory below, because my main goal here is to learn how to debug properly, so this is probably a long post about an otherwise trivial problem.

Here's the code, first:

```
/*Generate array with 500 to 1000 elements*/
/*In the calling function, I create something like 'int* x;' and pass '&x'*/

void gen_array(int** arr){
    int size = rand() % (1001 - 500) + 500;
    int i;

    *arr = (int*) malloc(size*sizeof(int));

    if (*arr == NULL){
        printf("Allocation failed\n");
        exit(1); //I know this is probably bad form
    }

    //Fill with some random numbers from 1 to 1000
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        *arr[i] = rand() % 1001;
}
```

It breaks after the first iteration in the `for` loop (that is, when `i==1`). I'm not sure if I'm allocating wrong with `malloc`, or assigning wrong in the loop.

Calling like this:

```
int* x = NULL; //Tried without '= NULL' as well
gen_array(&x);
```

## The specific error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00265E55 in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC.
```

This is *after* a [first-chance exception](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidklinems/2005/07/12/what-is-a-first-chance-exception/) at the exact same place, but they are generated at the same line of code (and on the same iteration during execution).

---

---

## My attempt at analyzing:

If it helps, here's the (relevant) step-by-step from debugging on one attempt (I'm compiling in Visual Studio). I'd like to know how to use this info to help me debug in the future.

- At the start of the calling function, `x = 0xcccccccc` (`0xcccccccc=-842150451` seems to be what the compiler uses to fill uninitialized values). After set to `NULL`, it's equal to `0x00000000` of course.
- Calling `gen_array(int** arr)`, since I'm passing a pointer to a pointer, the local 'double pointer' is an address pointing to the NULL pointer: `arr=0x0018facc {0x00000000 {???}}`. (This is showing the values of what's being pointed to, since the NULL pointer is pointing to nothing, there's `???`)
- Call to `malloc`: now `arr=0x0018facc {0x00e97048 {-842150451}}`, so `*arr` is pointing to an uninitialized value
- First iteration (`i==0`), the number generated is `588`, so now `arr=0x0018facc {0x00e97048 {588}}` (that is, the value that `*arr` is pointing at is `588`)

The next iteration crashes after `i` is increased to `1`. Since it's an access violation, I would typically guess that `arr+1` isn't expecting to be written to. But the violation location is at `0xCCCCCCCC`, the value that this compiler uses for uninitialized data. Is this because `arr+1` is technically uninitialized?

**Edit:** as @GrzegorzSzpetkowski advised, I tried changing `*arr[i]` to `(*arr)[i]`. It stopped breaking! but, no new random values are being created/placed into the array (which is why I'm concerned that an array isn't being created at all).

**Edit 2:** To @EOF's suggestion, I changed the function to return the size so I can call with something like `int length = gen_array(&x);`

---

I know I can also try returning an `int*` from the function, but I'd like to know what's going on specifically here in the case of passing the pointer from a calling function to be initialized.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: In Visual Studio, since it's compiling as C++, I get an error (the build fails) when I don't cast: `error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'int *'`

Comment: Have you included `stdlib`?

Comment: `*arr[i]` -> `(*arr)[i]` because postfix has higher precedence. The former lhs does not make sense in your context.

Comment: I have included `stdlib`.

Comment: Anyway, I believe you can force VS to compile it as C. And @GrzegorzSzpetkowski gave you the answer.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski, actually I should have mentioned that I tried that, and the function doesn't break, but when it returns, the array only has one value.

Comment: Edited main post with his advice

Comment: Your function is nonsense anyway. If the size of the allocation you create is random, and you don't have any way of informing the caller about it, the allocation *cannot* be safely accessed once the function returns.

Comment: @jaska How do you know it has one value? You don't know what was allocated and the items are random.

Comment: I'm guessing now that it's the wrong way to do it, but just by: `#define length(x) sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0])`. It works fine for another (statically allocated) array in the calling function.

Comment: It can work only for static arrays.

Comment: @EOF - okay, but, could you explain why not? How would it be different than doing the same thing in the calling function?

Comment: In calling function you would have the `size` variable accessible... Just make it a return value, so the caller knows how large is the array.

Comment: @jaska: How does the caller of this function know *how many elements it is allowed to access*? C doesn't have bounds-checking, if the caller of this function tries to access an element of the array beyond the end of the allocation, the behavior is *undefined*.

Comment: Gotcha - I see. I updated the post with your suggestion: I changed the function to return the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check operator precence of * and []
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

```
*arr[i] = rand() % 1001;
```

means

```
*(arr[i]) = rand() % 1001;
```

but you want

```
(*arr)[i] = rand() % 1001;
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one error is immediately obvious to me: when you initialize the array, you need `(*arr)[i] =`, not `*arr[i] =`.